# About definition of Harmonic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

$\rightarrow$ Definition : Real valued function from $\mathbb R^n$ is said to be Harmonic function if it has continuous first and second order partial derivatives and satisfy Laplace equation.

(1) in complex analysis for finding harmonic conjugate of some real valued function $u$ from $\mathbb R^2$ we only check  it satisfy Laplace equation or not.if it is then we find $v$ ,such that $u$ and $v$ satisfy CR equation.

My question is why we are not checking continuity of first and second order partial derivative.?

Does there exist function satisfying Laplce equation with discontinuous first or second order partial derivatives?

Comment: Laplace equation is elliptic hence any solution in any reasonable sense is very smooth (at least where it is a function)

Comment: @Conrad Then why we add those condition in definition?

Comment: Because the above result about the Laplacian is, while maybe not that difficult per se, still quite advanced requiring some PDE theory, distributions etc, while the study of harmonic functions usually goes in different directions which do not require those, so defining harmonic functions either as $C^2$ with $\Delta f=0$ (or sometimes just as continuous functions satisfying the mean value theorem) is much simpler